# How to symlink or alias a systemd template instance?

Tags: systemd

#### Summary

If I have a systemd template unit `foo@.service`, how can I symlink to or create an alias for a specific template instance, such that, for example, `bar.service` would be a shortcut for `foo@bar.service`?

#### Background

I have a couple of services run by docker-compose.

```
/var/docker-compose/nginx/docker-compose.yml
/var/docker-compose/nextcloud/docker-compose.yml
/var/docker-compose/diaspora/docker-compose.yml
```

To manage these services with systemd, I've adopted [an approach to use template units](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4266#issuecomment-302813256) in order to avoid duplication as all the docker-compose unit files would almost be the same.

```
# /etc/systemd/system/docker-compose@.service

[Unit]
Description=%i service with docker compose
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
Restart=always

WorkingDirectory=/var/docker-compose/%i

# Remove old containers, images and volumes
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker-compose down -v
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker-compose rm -fv
ExecStartPre=-/bin/bash -c 'docker volume ls -qf "name=%i_" | xargs docker volume rm'
ExecStartPre=-/bin/bash -c 'docker network ls -qf "name=%i_" | xargs docker network rm'
ExecStartPre=-/bin/bash -c 'docker ps -aqf "name=%i_*" | xargs docker rm'

# Compose up
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker-compose up %i

# Compose down, remove containers and volumes
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker-compose down -v

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

#### Goal

Now I would like to have aliases or symlinks to the individual services to make starting and stopping them a little shorter.

Rather than

```
systemctl stop docker-compose@nginx
```

I would like to type:

```
systemctl stop nginx
```

#### What does not work

- I've tried to create a symlink:

  ```
  cd /etc/systemd/system
  ln -s docker-compose@nginx.service nginx.service
  ```

  but `nginx.service` is not found when I want to start or stop it.
- I've tried to define an alias in the template unit:

  ```
  [Install]
  Alias=%i.service
  ```

  but, if I understand this correctly, this is [not allowed](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1090#issuecomment-566984723) and it did not work for me.
- I haven't found a way to "import" or "require" a base unit file and overwrite just the `WorkingDirectory` line. Then, I could create separate, short files like this:

  ```
  # /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service

  Import=docker-compose@.service

  WorkingDirectory=/var/docker-compose/nginx
  ```

Thanks!

Comment: I've posted my [workaround](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/630226/91720), but I'm still looking for a systemd solution.

Comment: Did you eventually find a proper solution?

Comment: @SamSirry: No, sorry. I'm using my [posted workaround](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/630226/91720) for now.

Comment: After adding that `Alias` line, you need to update `systemd` via `systemctl daemon-reload` and then you need re-enable the service.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to make use of the properties considered for unit names containing dashes (`-`) according to the [archlinux man pages](https://man.archlinux.org/man/systemd.unit.5.en), and it worked:

> Moreover for unit names containing dashes (`-`), the set of directories generated by repeatedly truncating the unit name after all dashes is searched too. Specifically, for a unit name `foo-bar-baz.service` not only the regular drop-in directory `foo-bar-baz.service.d/` is searched but also both `foo-bar-.service.d/` and `foo-.service.d/`.

and as another note from the man page:

> Along with a unit file `foo.service`, a "drop-in" directory `foo.service.d/` may exist. All files with the suffix `.conf` from this directory will be merged in the alphanumeric order and parsed after the main unit file itself has been parsed.

In my working example, this is the final structure of the files at the root of my unit search path (i.e., `/etc/systemd/system/`):

```
│    docker-a.service
│    docker-b.service  
│    docker-c.service
│
└─── docker-.service.d
    │    docker.conf
    │
```

Also, `docker.conf` and `docker-a.service` files are:

```bsh
# /etc/systemd/system/docker-.service.d/docker.conf

[Unit]
Description=We named our service [%j] service
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/arman/%j
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c 'echo "The prestart command for %j was done!" >> log.txt'
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'echo "The start command for %j was done!" >> log.txt'
```

```bsh
# /etc/systemd/system/docker-a.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=a.service
```

I did it with the following steps:

1. Firstly, create a drop-in directory like `docker-.service.d` at the root of a unit search path directory (e.g. `/etc/systemd/system`).
2. Then, create a `.conf` file like `docker.conf` at the created drop-in directory and write your `[Unit]` and `[Service]` sections in that file using the `%j` specifier:

> `%j`: This is the string between the last `-` and the end of the prefix name.

3. After that, create one service file for each of your intended services next to the drop-in directory in the root search path. They should just consist of the `[Install]` section to explicitly determine their alias name with the `Alias` option. (I also tried to put this section in the `docker.conf` file too, but the `[Install]` section could not be found when the services started.) Be careful that the names of these services should satisfy the constraints.
4. Now, If you run `systemctl enable docker-{alias}.service` for each created service, you'll be able to control the service just by its `{alias}`. That's it!

Comment: P.S. Step 3 clarification:
For example, in my case, the names obey the `docker-{alias}.service` format that `{alias}` is the alias service determined in the service file as the `Alias` option without the type suffix. (e.g. "nginx")

Comment: P.S. Step 4 clarification: 
It means if you've entered `Alias=nginx.service` in the `[Install]` section of service, by enabling the service, you can start it by running `systemctl start nginx`. That's it!

Comment: This feature appears in version 254 (the link to Archlinux shows that), but this "drop-in" directory searching feature is not present in systemd 219, which is what I have on CentOS 7.6.

Answer (score 0):

How about accepting that command as it is and just use bash aliased for your commandline:

File `~/.bash_aliases`

```
alias nginx-stop="systemctl stop docker-compose@nginx"
alias nginx-start="systemctl start docker-compose@nginx"
alias nextcloud-stop="systemctl stop docker-compose@nextcloud"
alias nextcloud-start="systemctl start docker-compose@nextcloud"
alias diaspora-stop="systemctl stop docker-compose@diaspora"
alias diaspora-start="systemctl start docker-compose@diaspora"
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought about that but didn't really like the idea: I think, my fingers just want to type `systemctl restart nginx` because of the many other machines I had nginx running without docker previously. I'm regarding bash aliases (and maybe accepting duplication and just copy/pasting the unit files) fallback solutions if I can't find a systemd-way of achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

The following workaround is not systemd-native but creates systemd service files using a [Rakefile](https://github.com/ruby/rake).

#### Workaround

This assumes that [ruby](http://ruby-lang.org) is installed on the host system.

1. Check that `/etc/systemd/system/docker-compose@.service` is present. Within this file `%i` is used as variable for the service name, e.g. "nginx".
2. Create a `Rakefile` in `/var/docker-compose/`:

   ```ruby
   # /var/docker-compose/Rakefile

   TEMPLATE_SERVICE_FILE = "/etc/systemd/system/docker-compose@.service"

   task :systemd_units do
     print "Creating systemd units:\n"

     Dir.glob("/var/docker-compose/*/docker-compose.yml").each do |compose_file|
       service_name = compose_file.split("/")[-2]
       unit_file = "/etc/systemd/system/#{service_name}.service"
       unit_file_content = File.read TEMPLATE_SERVICE_FILE
       unit_file_content.gsub! "%i", service_name
       File.write unit_file, unit_file_content
       print "#{unit_file}\n"
     end
   end
   ```
3. Run `rake` from the `/var/docker-compose/` directory.

This will explicitly create a separate unit file for each service, e.g. `/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service` based on the template file `/etc/systemd/system/docker-compose@.service`.

#### Pros:

- `systemctl start nginx` works
- `systemctl enable nginx` works
- Tab completion works

#### Cons:

- One has to re-run `rake` when changing the template file or adding/removing services from the docker-compose directory.